# Display div on hover for mapped buttons

Tags: html, reactjs, mapping

So I have a group of buttons that are displayed using a map. When I hover over one of these buttons I want a black box to appear on the side of it. This black box will be developed into a preview.

However, because of the map function, the rest of the buttons get a preview when I hover over one button. This is how the buttons look before the hover. You have a subject, and the courses are listed under this. Both the courses and subjects are mapped. [image]
When I hover over a single button all the button previews are set to true. When I move my mouse off the button, all the previews are removed. How can I single out a button to have a specific preview?
[image]

```js
export default function Yeartwo() {
  const [grade, setGrade] = useState(localStorage.getItem('grade'));
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState(false);
  let grades = Object.keys(courseData)
  let nextGrade = grades[Object.keys(courseData).indexOf(grade)+1]
  let subjects = courseData[nextGrade].subjects
  let courses = courseData[nextGrade].classes

function coursePreview(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('hovered')
  setPreview(true)
}

    return (
        <div className="courseSelect">

          {subjects.map((subject, index) => (

            <div key={index}>
              <h2 className="subject">{subject}</h2>
              <div className="courses">

              {courses[subject].map((course, index) => (

                <div key={index}>
                    <button value={subject} className="course_btn" onMouseEnter={() => setPreview(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setPreview(false)}>{course}</button>
                    {preview && <div className="preview"> {course} </div>}

                </div>
              ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>

  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reorder your preview state to contain an object instead of booleans. The object should be in the following format: `{ 'course1': boolean, 'course2': boolean, ..., 'courseN': boolean }` - `course` is the key and the `boolean` value represents whether the preview for this item should be shown or not.

Therefore, your condition should look like this: `{preview['course'] && <div className="preview"> {course} </div>}`

And update your listeners to be like this: `{... onMouseEnter={() => setPreview({...preview, 'course': true}) ...}` and the same for the onMouseLeave method.

Comment: The problem is that, my courses and subjects are dynamic. They are changing and not fixed. I may have 4 subjects on one page, but 7 on the other. Or one subject for one page has 3 courses, but the same subject on another page will have 7.

Comment: In the initial state of the preview, you will always have an empty object {}. This allows you to dynamically use my solution for any number of subjects. As for the issue of different counts of courses, if you have an array with courses that are assigned to a subject, you can map them in a single preview container.